# Loop through checkboxes and display checked if 'ID'=='ID'

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, checkbox

I'm fairly new to PHP. I have a page called `createemployee.php` that uses a `for` loop to display checkboxes used to define an employees skillset, the following code works:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($skills); $i++):?>
    <span class="description">
         <input  id="customCheck1" type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="<?=$skills[$i]['skill_id'];?>">
         <label class=" badge badge-warning" for="customCheck1"><?=$skills[$i]["skill_name"]?></label>
    </span>
<?php endfor;?>
```

I'm trying to create a page for `editemployee.php` in which the details of a specific employee is loaded and editable by the user. I would like to display checked values if the checkbox was checked.

I am using a linking table to allow one employee to have multiple skills, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_skill (
emp_skill_id INT PRIMARY KEY UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
emp_id INT UNSIGNED,
skill_id INT UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY emp_id REFERENCES employee(`emp_id`),
FOREIGN KEY skill_id REFERENCES skill(`skill_id`)
);
```

If I nest `for` loops like so (this is wrong, but testing=learning and it gave me an output similar to what I'm wanting), the output is printed with the correct checkboxes selected, but the data taken from skills is duplicated each time it is equal to emp_skill (due to nesting `for` loops).

```
 <?php for($j = 0; $j < count($emp_skill); $j++):?>
  <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($skills); $i++):?>
      <span class="description">
          <input  id="customCheck1" type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="<?=$skills[$i]['skill_id'];?>" 
          <?php if ($skills[$i]["skill_id"]==$emp_skill[$j]['skill_id']) echo 'checked="checked"';?>>
          <label class=" badge badge-warning" for="customCheck1"><?=$skills[$i]["skill_name"]?></label>
     </span>
 <?php endfor;?>
<?php endfor;?>
```

How can I output checked values if $skill.skill_id is matching a row within the $emp_skill.skill_id without duplicating the output of $skill on the webpage?

I assume I will need to use a loop of some kind (maybe `foreach` or `while`, opposed to `for`).

Comment: How are you creating `$emp_skill` and `$skills`?  Also, it's not related to your problem, but one thing you're doing wrong (in both the create and edit pages) is `id="customCheck1"`.  Every HTML element should have a unique id.  You are using the same id for all of the checkboxes.  This will become problematic if you use Javascript and want to attach events to the checkboxes by id.

Comment: Thank you @Patrick-Q, I will seperate the id's :)
I am using prepared statements to get results from two seperate select queries for emp_skill and skills, like so:
...
  while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $skills[] = array(
        "skill_id" => $skill_id,
        "skill_name" => $skill_name);
        $stmt->close();
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get your message. But let me explain what I got.

You want to select checkboxes whose ids are in the `skill_id` column in `emp_skill` table.

I think you can select all the skill_id for the employee and loop over the skill and then check if the skill_id is in the employee skills

Here's the implementation:

```
$employeeSkillIds = array_column($emp_skill, 'skill_id');

<?php foreach($skills as $skill) :?>
      <span class="description">
          <input  id="customCheck1" type="checkbox" name="skills[]" value="<?= $skill['skill_id'];?>" 
          <?= in_array($skill['skill_id'],$employeeSkillIds) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ;?>>
          <label class=" badge badge-warning" for="customCheck1"><?=$skill["skill_name"]?></label>
     </span>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```